# How do I unhide a card in Mint?

Tags: mint.com

I accidentally hid the Budgets summary card from my Overview in Mint. (Gear Icon → Hide Card). Now the card is missing every time I login.

How can I unhide the Budgets card from my Overview?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **Settings → Overview Features** to hide or unhide cards on your Overview page.

1. Log in to your account on [mint.com](https://mint.intuit.com/login.event).
2. Click **Settings** in the top menu bar.
3. Open [**Overview Features**](https://mint.intuit.com/settings.event?filter=hideoverview) in the left sidebar.
4. Find the card you want to unhide and check **Show on Overview**.

You can also rearrange cards from this screen by dragging the ☰ icon.

[image: Settings - Overview Features]